Limit number of unacknowledged messages per queue
Is there a way to restrict the number of messages that "in flight" with consumers at the queue level?
For example, if there are 3 consumers (for resiliency purposes), and I want to ensure that a message is acked (or nacked/failed) by a consumer before the next message is sent to any of the consumers. There are probably other ways to solve the problem using an external locking service, but is there a way to do it in RabbitMQ directly?
I looked at using prefetch limits, but this appears to only support per-consumer or per-channel, rather than across a queue.
